# Django Rest Framework URL pattern with parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an Angular/DRF application.

What I want is to send an object to my backend to process it:

```
 var data = {'url': url, 'name': name}
 return this.http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/record/json=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data)))
```

Because my data as URL in it, I URI encode it to escape the "/"

Then in DRF this my urls.py:

```
path('record/<str:music_details>', record_views.Record.as_view(), name='record'),
```

And my views.py:

```
class Record(View):

    def get(self, request):
        json_string = request.query_params['json']
        data = json.loads(json_string)
        print(data)
```

I have nothing printing in my console, I assume my url path is wrong, how should I fix it?

Comment: Your request looks to have an extra `/api` preceding the record part of the url. Unless you're explicitly adding this somewhere in django, I don't think you need it

Comment: I need it because every incoming requests strarting with `/api` are redirected to this urls.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Send query parameter after `?` like:

```
var data = {'url': url, 'name': name}
return this.http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/record?json=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data)))
```

Modify `urls.py`:

```
path('record', record_views.Record.as_view(), name='record'),
```

and fetch from query as:

```
json_string = request.GET.get('json')
```

**Solution 2:**

Send data with `json=` like:

```
var data = {'url': url, 'name': name}
return this.http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/record/" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data)))
```

and modify `get` method to fetch data as:

```
class Record(View):

    def get(self, request, music_details):
        data = json.loads(music_details)
        print(data)
```

Comment: First is working fine. What's the diference between the two?

Comment: In solution 1, data is being sent in query string or get method, which is in key:value form and starts after `?`. In solution 2, data included as URI itself which are called query parameters.